# Elements fail to form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the vector space $P^2$ and the set

$$5−1t+4t^2,−4+3t+1t^2,8+5t+kt^2$$

For which $k \in \mathbb{R}$, do these three elements fail to be a basis of $P^2$?

I thought in order to make the three elements fail to be a basis, one of the elements must be redundant. But I have no idea how to make one of the elements a linear combination of the other two.

I tried
$$-2(5−1t+4t^2)+−4+3t+1t^2=-14+5t-7t^2=8+5t+kt^2$$
which makes $-22=(k+7)t^2$

But I do not what the value of $t$ is. So I was stuck. Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Do you know about determinants?

Comment: @Kior you are trying to write a specific linear combination to be equal to the third polynomial. This will not work. Linear dependence means $\exists$ a linear combination, not necessarily the one you have chosen. So there is a flaw in your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider a linear combination of these three vectors which equals the zero vector (polynomial)
\begin{align*}
x(5−1t+4t^2)+y(−4+3t+1t^2)+z(8+5t+kt^2) & =\mathbf{0}\\
t^2(4x+y+kz)+t(-x+3y+5z)+(5x-4y+8z) & = \mathbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
By linear independence of $1,t,t^2$ we get the following system:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4&1&k\\
-1&3&5\\
5&-4&8
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathbf{0}.
$$

Now you want a non-trivial (non-zero) solution to this system. So find a $k$ which makes this matrix non-invertible etc...